# Is there a way for shutting down pc using PHP

Tags: php, windows, browser

I have an idea, and i have a single php local web page running on localhost

and i want to use GUI for 3 buttons : **shut down** , **sleep** and **restart**

Is PHP allows to me for these operations? Are there ready to write classes, methods in PHP?

Comment: You should be asking yourself, "Is PHP the right tool for this job?"  Wouldn't it be much easier to click `start -> shut down`?

Comment: i want to learn PHP's power and usability, and i want to improve myself at php :)

Comment: Check out the shell_exec() function. I think you also have to use a shell script as well (to receive the function call)

Comment: `system('shutdown -r now');`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your Apache/PHP configuration is setup to allow the use of `system`, then you can use that.

For *nix systems:

```
system('shutdown now');    // shutdown
// or
system('reboot');          // reboot
system('shutdown -r now'); // also reboot :)
```

For Windows:

```
system('shutdown -t -s 0'); // shutdown
// or
system('shutdown -r -t 0'); // reboot
```

[More info here.](https://superuser.com/a/188741/109474)

As far as sleep/standby on *nix is concerned, it varies a lot.

---

**Note**: You can also use `shell_exec()` or `exec()`.

---

EDIT:

Per user1597430's comment, in *nix systems you can pass the `-h` (halt) option which will essentially shut down and *halt* the CPUs but not disconnect the main power.

```
system('shutdown -h now'); // shutdown and halt
system('shutdown -P now'); // shutdown and power off
```

Server fault [has some great answers here about this](https://serverfault.com/a/191541).

Comment: "shutdown -r now" - I believe that -r means reboot on any contemporary *nix. "shutdown now" is shutdown.

Comment: hello from the future, `shutdown -h now` is even better

Answer (score 4):

Almost all languages will have to do a system call.

```
shutdown -s -t 0
```

That is more or less the magic bullet. Java, for instance, could call it like this:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

PHP would be something like this

```
<?php
exec ('shutdown -s -t 0');
?>
```

But the thing is PHP is an interpreted language, compiled by a web-server that is signaled to run by an end user so it's probably way messy for that sort of behavior. It's like using a chainsaw to trim your nails...

Answer (score 0):

You can call shell script from php which will shut down , sleep and restart you computer it can be done on linux based machine, but not sure whether it is possible on Windows pc

Comment: Hi Pankaj, your answer would be a heck of a lot more useful if you included an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a .bat file with PHP on Windows.

```
<?php echo exec('reboot.bat'); ?>
```

Content of the .bat file:

shutdown example:

```
C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe -s -c "Shutdown the computer."
```

reboot example:

```
C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe -r -c "Rebooting for latest updates."
```

StandByModus

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState
```