# How to shut down pc using curl

Tags: javascript, php, windows, curl, browser

How to shut down windows 10 pc using curl command from web browser. Please help me. Or any other way to shutdown the pc from web browser would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since I am using js to built the web app and also all browser supports Js ... and I think it may be possible  to shutdown pc using nodejs . My whole point  is to shutdown a pc from web browser

Comment: Hit any page with your curl and in that page write code to execute this cmd "shutdown.exe /s /t 00" . I am not sure what programming language you're using , But most programming language can run console cmds.

Comment: There may be issues like to start the console as admin so make sure that your programming language can run things as admin.

Comment: [Shutdown computer via web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628335/shutdown-computer-via-web-page)

Comment: I am building simple single web page app using javascript and php. I heard it is not possible  to shutdown a pc from web browser, and I am wonderingn if curl can do that. So are you saying that I can ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538970/is-there-a-way-for-shutting-down-pc-using-php